# Quick way to do "is many"?

Tags: java

let's say we have an interface IMyInterface that has a few methods. Now I want a class that is a collection of objects implementing IMyInterface.

If there was only one method I could just do something like

```
class ManyMyInterface{
  List<IMyInterface> interfaces = new ArrayList<>();

  void doSomething(){
    for(IMyInterface i : interfaces){
      i.doSomething();
    }
  }
}
```

But if I have a lot of methods, this process becomes tedious. Is there some faster way, like with a callable where I can just do something like

```
foreach function in IMyInterface do
  ManyMyInterface.class.addfunction(function.name, function.parameters,{
  for(IMyInterface i : interfaces){
    i.function();
  }
});
```

I know java doesn't easily add functions like the pseudocode above due to the way the classloader behaves, but is there a hack or ingenious way to reproduce this type of behavior?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You can always use reflection, with the expected performance penalties.

Comment: You can solve this with lambdas in Java 8.

Comment: I prefer this way you are complaining about. There's almost no way to make bugs in such small methods and lots of small methods look like the right code, not the wrong code. If `ManyMyInterface` implemented `IMyInterface`, it would look like the composite design pattern, and using design patterns is the right way to write programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Java 8 you can use a `Consumer<IMyInterface>`:

```
void apply(Consumer<IMyInterface> consumer) {
    for(IMyInterface i : interfaces){
        consumer.accept(i);
    }
}
```

and call the method with:

```
apply(i -> i.doSomething());
```

or with a method reference:

```
apply(IMyInterface::doSomething);
```

With Java 7- you can provide an anonymous class that implements a similar interface.